# How to check if response is of specific interface type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am writing a integration test.

It passes but the only way I know if it passes is by checking if the response type is an object like so:

```
describe('INTEGRATION test1', () => {
  it('get user from service success', async () => {
    const serviceObj: IFindPropsRequest = {
      find: {
        findMeta: {
          prop1: 'value1',
          prop2: 'Individual',
        }
    };
    const resp: ServiceResponse<IFindResponse> = await findProfileService(serviceObj, 'DE');

    expect(typeof resp).toBe('object'); // want to change this
  });
```

instead of `expect(typeof resp).toBe('object');` I am looking for a way to see if 
resp is of type `IFindResponse`

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try `instanceof` like this: `resp instanceof IFindResponse`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't. `interface` is something that's removed during runtime, so when your application is running there's no facility to see if an arbitrary incoming object can satisfy a type of interface.

The typescript way of handing this is to write a type guard, but it involves you manually writing the code to see if the incoming type satisfies the interface.

We've solved this by not using typescript. We write JSON-Schema for runtime validation, and actually have scripts that take the JSON-Schema files and convert them to typescript types for static analysis. Not saying that answers your question, but the point here is that you need something that does this at runtime, and Typescript aint it.

The 'crazy hack' is if you get the response, convert it to a .ts file and manually invoke the typescript compiler on the created files... Not sure if this is a road you want to go down.. but it's a possibility.

Comment: A valid point. This got me looking for an alternative way which I will present below. This is a correct answer to the question but after reading this I changed my approach. See my answer for details. Accepting this.

Answer (score 0):

You can expect **true** when `resp instanceof IFindResponse` as @Max commented.

```
expect(resp instanceof IFindResponse).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Have you tested this? instanceof will only work for classes.

Comment: I am getting IFindResponse is not defined when running the test. IFindResponse  is an interface

Answer (score 0):

After reading @Evert answer I approached this in another way:

```
describe('INTEGRATION test1', () => {
  it('get user from service success', async () => {
    const serviceObj: IFindPropsRequest = {
      find: {
        findMeta: {
          prop1: 'value1',
          prop2: 'Individual',
        }
    };
    const resp: ServiceResponse<IFindResponse> = await findProfileService(serviceObj, 'DE');

    expect(resp.data.customers).toBeTruthy(); check if property exists
  });
```

I basically just checked if the response had a property that it will only have if the request vent through.

The same solution, but with a typeguard:

```
describe('INTEGRATION test1', () => {
  it('get user from service success', async () => {
    const serviceObj: IFindPropsRequest = {
      find: {
        findMeta: {
          prop1: 'value1',
          prop2: 'Individual',
        }
    };
    const resp: ServiceResponse<IFindResponse> = await findProfileService(serviceObj, 'DE');

    expect(isIFindResponse(resp)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  function isIFindResponse(input: any): input is IFindResponse {
    return input.data.customers !== undefined;
  }
```

Comment: If you want a slightly nicer way to write this, you might like to actually write the typeguard function. It's a bit more reusable and makes it more apparently what the purpose is of checking for the `.data.customers` property.

Comment: @Evert Risk of asking to much from you but how would I go on about writing such a typeguard? Im fairly new.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your answer to add it in. You might not care for a typeguard (it's a bit more writing), but it's a nice pattern because Typescript actually understands this typeguard. Which means that if you do anything *after* calling isIFindResponse, typescript will no longer treat it as `any`.

Another (similar) tool is an assertion